# Content Query Web Part for multiple lists

Tags: list, custom-list, error, content-query-web-part

In my site collection, I have a bunch of custom lists that contain Requests that employees have submitted (IT Request, Maintenance Request, etc...).  I'm trying to set up a CQWP that aggregates all these lists and displays a neatly organized list for the current user.  However, every time I try and set up the query in the CQWP all I get is the error message: "`There is a problem with the query that this Web Part is issuing.  Check the configuration of this Web Part and try again`.

From what I can tell, everything I set up is pretty simple but I just can't seem to get any results from the query whatsoever.

Thanks for any help I can get.